# Why is WiFi signal strength low on my INSPIRON 15 5559?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Okay so I recently bought this laptop everything is perfect except wifi signal is extremely low even when I am next to router it only receives maximum of 2 bars on windows 10. When I purchased this laptop from my local store I told them to swap 8 gigs of memory instead of 4, so i'm thinking maybe while they made the swap the wifi adapter got loose or something? Can anyone help me on what I should do? Its really frustrating to use WiFi on low signal! :(

p.s: should I try to un-mount and mount the card again?

Comment: I'd take it back to the store and get them to either fix it, replace it or refund my money.

Comment: As I can see in Youtube, on the model 5558 you have access to the compartiment that allocates the Wi-Fi card. You could check if the antenna cable is firmly attached to it.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick taking back isn't an option right now as i'm a thousand miles away from that pace.

Comment: it's still present! :(